# How can we enable cache for a page in drupal5 for authenticated users?

Tags: views, performance, caching, 5

I am using drupal5 for my website. Certain pages in my site are loading very slowly. I came across several posts suggesting to use the caching capabilities of Drupal. After enabling cache pages started loading at a faster rate from cache for anonymous users . How can I improve the performance for an authenticate user? or How can I enable cache for authenticated users, say for a single page?

The page which I am trying to load uses a view and has limited number of filters applied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you improve Drupal performance?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24180/how-do-you-improve-drupal-performance)