# Exporting large data using cron

Tags: cron, importing-exporting

I am working on a website which has around 150k users.
I have to create a csv file which contains the details of user (drupal fields and profile2 fields ) and export the csv to another server daily.

I have implemented by export function in a hook_cron and in the function i do a user_load function call and two profile2_load_by_user and some other custom mysql queries.

The problem which i have is that my export_function does not seem to terminate, it may be a timeout or a memory problem.

I have tested my function my limiting the number of users to around 1000 and it works fine.

I am wondering whether it is possible to export huge volume of data through hook_cron.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this in chunks.I mean schedule you cron using [elysia_cron](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) or [ultimate cron](https://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) at every hour or something and export chunks of users at a time,flag users you exported and at every next cron run get the new ones.

One **important** thing you should have crontab set on your server,do not use drupal's default poormanscron.

Answer (score 1):

I work with large data sets in the form of Webform results. To export 60k records with 30+ columns of data I had to kick the memory limit up in my .htaccess file.

```
# FILE: .htaccess
# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quo...
  ...
  # 2013-09-30 -- These new settings have been put in place so that the data dump (download) for the webform module doesn't exceed memory limits causing it to crash. -- 512 to 1024
  php_value memory_limit 1024M
  php_value max_execution...
</IfModule>
```

you may also want to change your php_value max_execution_time from 180 to something a little higher if your request is timing out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a [drush command](http://drush.ws/docs/commands.html) that retrieves and saves the data via batch or queue. This [article](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-batch-api) may come handy which provides the following code examples:

```
function mymodule_setup_batch($start=1, $stop=100000) {
  //  ...
  //  Populate $lots_of_data from record $start to record $stop.
  //  ...

  //Break up all of our data so each process does not time out.
  $chunks = array_chunk($lots_of_data, 20);
  $operations = array();
  $count_chunks = count($chunks);

  //for every chunk, assign some method to run on that chunk of data
  foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $i++;
    $operations[] = array("mymodule_method_to_work_on_a_small_part", array( $chunk ,'details'=> t('(Importing chunk @chunk  of  @count)', array('@chunk '=>$i, '@count'=>$count_chunks))));
    $operations[] = array("mymodule_another_method",array($chunk));
  }

  //put all that information into our batch array
  $batch = array(
    'operations' => $operations,
    'title' => t('Import batch'),
    'init_message' => t('Initializing'),
    'error_message' => t('An error occurred'),
    'finished' => 'mymodule_finished_method'
  );

  //Get the batch process all ready!
  batch_set($batch);
  $batch =& batch_get();

  //Because we are doing this on the back-end, we set progressive to false.
  $batch['progressive'] = FALSE;

  //Start processing the batch operations.
  drush_backend_batch_process();
}

function mymodule_method_to_work_on_a_small_part ($chunk, $operation_details, &$context) {
  //Do something to $chunk, maybe create a node?
  $context['message'] = $operation_details; //Will show what chunk we're on.
}
function mymodule_another_method($chunk, &$context) {
  //Do some more work.
  $context['message'] = t('We have done a second thing to a chunk of data');
}

function mymodule_finished_method($success, $results, $operations) {
  //Let the user know we have finished!
  print t('Finished importing!');
}
```

If you like, you can implement Drush command, e.g.

```
function mymodule_drush_command() {
  $items  = array();
  $items['myimport'] = array(
    'callback'    => 'mymodule_setup_batch',
    'description' => dt('Import'),
    'arguments'   => array(
      'start'     => "start",
      'stop'      => "stop",
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_drush_help($section) {
  switch ($section) {
    case 'drush:myimport':
      return dt("import items from the Internal Database [start record] [end record].");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8, you can use [Default Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content) module to export users into CSV file via `drush` command which can be invoked periodically by adding into the system's crontab. It's better to approach, as having big chunk of data exports in `hook_cron`, as it's blocking the other important processing.

---

Another way is to create a View which exports users in CSV format by using [Views Datasource module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource). Then you can enable caching, so the results are cached.

---

As the suggestion, to avoid using too many resources on processing and memory (such as a huge number of calls to `user_load`), you should implement memory caching service such as Redis or Memcached. Further more, please check: [How do you improve Drupal performance?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/24180/1908)

---

If you still got the issue, use PHP profiler (such as XDebug) to find the cause of your issue.