# Improve extremely slow 'drupal_process_form'

Tags: 7, forms, entities, performance, debugging

I am having problem investigating why our profile edit page is damn slow.

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  276344  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   1.6889  39666816    menu_execute_active_handler( )  ...\index.php:21
3   1.6899  39668968    call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\hyperDrupal\includes\menu.inc:527} ( )    ...\menu.inc:527
4   1.6899  39669448    entity_ui_get_form( )   ...\menu.inc:527
5   1.6901  39696720    drupal_build_form( )    ...\entity.module:1282
6   1.7842  40984120    drupal_process_form( )  ...\form.inc:385
(7) 17.3247 58502824    form_execute_handlers( )    ...\form.inc:903
8   17.3247 58503344    profile2_form_submit_handler( ) ...\form.inc:1519
9   17.3265 58492400    profile2_save( )    ...\profile2.module:621
10  17.3265 58492528    Profile->save( )    ...\profile2.module:311
11  17.3265 58491736    Entity->save( ) ...\profile2.module:918
12  17.3265 58492096    EntityAPIController->save( )    ...\entity.inc:333
13  17.3737 58517352    EntityAPIController->invoke( )  ...\entity.controller.inc:462
(14)    23.5502 90243232    module_invoke_all( )    ...\entity.controller.inc:355
15  23.5511 90247648    call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\hyperDrupal\includes\module.inc:951} ( )  ...\module.inc:951
16  23.5511 90248096    bdEvent_entity_update( )    ...\module.inc:951
17  23.5511 90248832    bdE\bdEvent->dispatch( )    ...\bdEvent.module:44
18  23.5567 90332840    bdE\Services\profileService->run( ) ...\bdEvent.php:38
19  23.5568 90333120    bdE\Services\profileService->entity_get_values( )   ...\profileService.php:24
```

I created a stack trace in a new module and times are huge. Check step 7 and 14 both are after long operations.

What could be taking so much between

```
6   1.7842  40984120    drupal_process_form( )  ...\form.inc:385
7   17.3247 58502824    form_execute_handlers( )    ...\form.inc:903
```

and between

```
13  17.3737 58517352    EntityAPIController->invoke( )  ...\entity.controller.inc:462
14  23.5502 90243232    module_invoke_all( )    ...\entity.controller.inc:355
```

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing what that form is doing to take so long.

Comment: it's a simpler form I inherited using around 7 fields, all selects eg: country, city.

Comment: `drupal_process_form` executes the validators and submit handlers, including custom ones. Please post the form code, and any relevant submit handlers/validators etc. Without that, your guess is as good as mine. Also XHProf is probably more useful than a stack dump.

Comment: Useful starting point for XHProf: [Profiling Drupal 7 performance with XHProf and Devel](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/profiling-drupal-7-performance-xhprof-and-devel/)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the backtrace, you won't know why your site is slow.

You should run a proper PHP profiler and analyse the results which can identify the slowest components.

It doesn't have to be Drupal it-self, but could be lack of caching or misconfiguration.

Some suggestions:

- disable modules which you don't need (e.g. [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel), core Database Logging module, etc.),
- upgrade your PHP to the latest or higher branch,
- recompile your PHP for 64-bit or higher architecture depending on your CPU,
- use the faster storage device for your db files or whole LAMP environment (e.g. SSD or [memory-based filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs)),
- use PHP debugger or profiler to find out any performance bottleneck (e.g. [XDebug Profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler), [DTrace](http://php.net/manual/en/features.dtrace.php) or [NuSphere PhpED PHP Profiler](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_profiler.htm)),
- run some time-consuming drush command under [gprof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof) profiling tool, so you can find some performance bottleneck as well.

If disabling slow modules or profiling won't help, see: [How do you improve Drupal performance?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/24180/1908)